# Sql table output

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I've been given two tables: Employee and Staff

```
|ID| Name  |Surname|Postion|           |EmpID|ManID|
----------------------------           ------------- 
|1 |Scrooge|McDuck |Manager|           |3    |1    |
|2 |Daisy  |Duck   |Manager|           |7    |1    |
|3 |Donald |Duck   |Support|           |6    |2    | 
|4 |Minny  |Mouse  |Support|           |4    |2    |
|5 |Mickey |Mouse  |Support|           |2    |1    |
|6 |Goofy  |       |Support|           |1    |2    |
|7 |Pluto  |       |Support|           |5    |2    |
|8 |Huey   |Duck   |Support|
|9 |Dewey  |Duck   |Support|
|10|Louie  |Duck   |Support|
```

I am asked for a sql statement that will produce following output

```
| Name  |Surname|Postion|Manager Name|Manager Positon|          
------------------------            
|Donald |Duck   |Support|Scrooge     |Manager         
|Pluto  |       |Support|Scrooge     |Manager         
|Goofy  |       |Support|Daisy       |Manager        
|Minny  |Mouse  |Support|Daisy       |Manager       
|Daisy  |Duck   |Support|Scrooge     |Manager        
|Scrooge|McDuck |Manager|Daisy       |Manager        
|Mickey |Mouse  |Manager|Daisy       |Manager
```

So far I've created a view which displays everything but doesn't create the two new columns and doesn't give the names of the managers.

```
CREATE VIEW example
AS
    SELECT * FROM Employee
    JOIN StaffLink
    ON Employee.ID = StaffLink.EmpID

    SELECT 
GO
```

Please guide me.

Comment: Do a primary select of ``ManID`` and then every ``EmpId`` that matches that ``ManID``

Comment: There are lots of ways to approach this, but for valid testing, I think you'd need to clean up your data.  You've got people (characters?) reporting to each other.  Daisy reports to Scrooge, and Scrooge reports to Daisy.

Answer (score 1):

SQL:

```
SELECT Staff.EmpID, Manager.Name AS `Manager Name`, 
       Manager.Position AS `Manager Position`, 
       Employee.Name, Employee.Surname, Employee.Position
FROM (Staff, Employee AS Manager, Employee)
WHERE Manager.ID = Staff.ManID AND
      Employee.ID = Staff.EmpID;
```

I believe it is now fixed

Comment: This works except it alters the employees names to the managers names unfortunately

Comment: I believe I fixed the bug

Comment: Why not use inner join syntax?

Comment: @ChrisFarmer explain?